# python: generate 24bit hash

Tags: python, hash

I want to generate a 24-bit-length hash from strings.
After some googling, I found this: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/164274-fixed-size-cache/ , but it seems to be too complex.
Are there other, simpler, ways to generate a 24-bit hash?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are 32-bit hashes no good?

Comment: i need to generate ObjectID for mongo document, it accepts only 24bit hex values or 12-bit binary values.

Comment: That doesn't make too much sense. Hex is a representation of binary...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does it need to by cryptographically secure? I think you could probably just truncate one of the hashes from `hashlib`.

Comment: no, no need. but truncating will increase chance of appearing duplicates, or am i wrong?

Comment: @Anthony: Using a smaller hash value will anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You could compute a 24-bit CRC check value and use it as a hash value. The Wikipedia article on [cyclic redundancy check](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRC32) describes how to do this for n-bit CRCs and even has several generator polynomials for 24-bits in its [Polynomial representations of cyclic redundancy checks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check#Polynomial_representations_of_cyclic_redundancy_checks) section.